# Nodejs electron: focusOut event?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I'm toying around with electron, the framework used for the atom text editor, but I'm having a little trouble finding a basic feature. I'm working on a little system tray gui that I want to pop up in that respective corner of the screen. When you click elsewhere on the screen, not on my window, I would like for the window to hide itself. For that, I would normally use a focusOut event callback or something similar. Does that event exist in electron, because all I've found is the focus event.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you talking about a BrowserWindow losing focus? If so the [`blur`](https://github.com/atom/electron/blob/v0.36.7/docs/api/browser-window.md#event-blur) event seems to be what you're looking for.

Comment: Wow, that is not aptly named. If i had literally just glanced up a couple lines on the docs... thanks -_-.

Comment: I guess you can blame some committee for that one :) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/blur